# Is there a standard 'null' mime-type

Tags: ajax, json, http, mime-types, content-type

I am using a single JSON response format to cover a number of possible responses.

The response contains a field that, optionally, contains a link to an external resource.

The response is valid, regardless of whether this field is populated.

I am using a separate mime-type field to dictate how the client should handle said field.

i.e.

```
mime-type : video/mp4
```

Client plays the video

```
mime-type : text/html
```

Client launches a browser with the given URL

What I would like to know, is if there is a "standard" mime-type to cover an empty resource.
I know I can use a vendor specific mime-type, and most likely will, but it made me question.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer is no there isn't as a media type can only be defined if something actually exists.

Alternatively I would argue that depending on the system there may be a default for example one system may default to send "text/plain" while a web form may result in "multipart/form-data" by default.

I think it really depends on where the data is being sent from and how it is defined when sent.

Comment: I've seen `application/x-empty` used in cases where there was no content provided. Perhaps you can use that one?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with DanielTate's comment on the original question:  I don't think there is a "null media type" (media type a.k.a. MIME type).  I haven't looked through the [entire IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), but I very much doubt there's anything there.  The [media type RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) doesn't appear to mention anything like this -- I haven't read the whole thing, but did scan the TOC and search around for "null" "empty" "invalid".

What's clear is:  media type is supposed to be metadata about *something*.  Given your question, I'm trying to guess why you might be thinking about a null media type (if you added some specific json examples in your question, it might be clearer), but, generally speaking, it just doesn't make much sense:  in theory, you shouldn't need to describe *nothing* (i.e., a non-existing resource) with any kind of media type:  there's already nothing there, so why describe it further as having a "null media type"?

If I understand your situation correctly, when there is no resource, I would just use an empty string.  Maybe that's the null media type :)  But, for some reason, you seem to really want to specify a media type in your response, even when there's no resource (or no link).  Why is that?

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to do this, but one use case I can see is to send an Accept header in HTTP to specify that you don't expect to get anything back.

Answer (score 1):

The IANA reserves "example" for, well, example purposes. But since "example" shall never be used as a real mime type, `example/example` could serve as an (internally used) compatible "null" MIME type.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#examples

> **example**
>
> Note: The 'example' media type is used for examples. Any subtype
>   following the media type syntax may be used in those examples. No
>   subtype can be registered with IANA. For more information
>   see[RFC4735].
>
> Note: The occurrence of an 'example' media type as a media type
>   outside of examples, e.g. in a Content-Type header, is an error and
>   should be reported to the implementor.[RFC2045][RFC2046]  specifies
>   that Content Types, Content Subtypes, Character Sets, Access  Types,
>   and conversion values for MIME mail will be assigned and listed  by
>   the IANA.

Answer (score -1):

jus add a comma at the end

```
if( checkType( $_FILES["CV"]["type"], "application/pdf,image/jpeg,image/png,video/mp4,audio/mpeg,application/msword,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document," ) ) {
```