# how to set no content-type using apache httpclient

Tags: apache, httpclient

i am facing one issue on apache httpclient(the latest release)

i am using

```
builder.addPart("_sid", new StringBody("abcd"));
```

to build form part, but in server, the request info is:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_sid"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

i want the http client do not send the two lines:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

is there any code could help me?

Answer (score 0):

refer to [In apache http client, how to keep the Content-Type in a StringBody as empty or null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215956/in-apache-http-client-how-to-keep-the-content-type-in-a-stringbody-as-empty-or?rq=1) , i get the key:

```
 - FormBodyPart bodyPart = new FormBodyPart("_sid", new StringBody(sessionID, ContentType.DEFAULT_TEXT)) {
            @Override
            protected void generateContentType(ContentBody body) {
            }
            @Override
            protected void generateTransferEncoding(final ContentBody body){
            }

        };
```